# Xamarin CornerRadius behavior - Frame and ImageButton

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some problems using the CornerRadius in Xamarin.Forms. I want to have an ImageButton and a Frame (which holds an Image) that have CornerRadius=100. 
That works just fine on Android but does not work as expected when running it on iOS:
The Frame is not a circle anymore and the ImageButton disappears.

[Picture of iOS and Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPwsl.jpg)

My code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="FrameTest.MainPage">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" 
                     Grid.Column="0" 
                     BackgroundColor="#fc85ae" 
                     CornerRadius="100" 
                     Padding="2" 
                     Source="settings_wheel.png"
                     HeightRequest="40" 
                     WidthRequest="40"
                     HorizontalOptions="End"/>

        <Frame Grid.Row="1" 
               Grid.Column="0" 
               BorderColor="Black"
               CornerRadius="100"
               HeightRequest="100"
               WidthRequest="100"
               IsClippedToBounds="True"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Image x:Name="ProfilePictureView"
               BackgroundColor="#fc85ae" />
        </Frame>
</Grid>
```

Xamarin.Essentials: 1.3.1
Xamarin.Forms: 4.3.0.908675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it works on Android but not on iOS. To achieve circle on both platforms you have to divide HeightRequest / 2. This is your correct CornerRadius.